# Angular 2 base href from environment variable

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'd like to have a different base href in my Angular 2 app for dev and for production.

I've seen answers to questions that are similar (and some identical) to this one.

The best answer here summarizes well 2 solutions that are repeated in all the answers to these questions:

[Set base href from an environment variable with ng build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41515028/set-base-href-from-an-environment-variable-with-ng-build)

I tried both, each has its own problems:

1) `APP_BASE_HREF` - doesn't work for js/css files. For instance when trying to request **app/someroute/1**, it'll attempt to request the js and css files from app/someroute/1 instead of from app.

2) Modifiying base href in `ngOnInit` - by the time `ngOnInit` is called, the js and css files have already been requested and so the modified base href doesn't apply to the files loaded on init, only to files requested afterwards (which doesn't help me).

The only thing that works for me so far is to manually modify the html for production after each compilation, but I'm trying to automate it.

Possible solutions:

1) Altering base href before js and css files are requested - is there a way to do that? They're basically requested immediately on page load. Possibly adding a scripts which is executed in head before link rel?

2) Compiling different HTMLs for dev and production with different base href values, e.g. with some sort of very lightweight html template engine that won't be an overkill.

What do you think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out there's a cli option for that (requested by the community) --base-href.

I'm simply building for production like that:

ng build --prod --base-href=/prod_dir/

Comment: Problem is, `--base-href` doesn't seem to be supported in `ng serve`, so it cannot be tested easily. :-(

Comment: In the first place I was using it to supply a base-url for production, hence ng build. Why isn't it easy to test that? It takes slightly longer to compile but other than that I don't see a problem.

Comment: I use --base-href add the language to the url, but I am currently having problems because I can't test it with `ng serve`. If you don't need to do this, it's not a problem.

Comment: In that case maybe use environment variables to specify language? I guess it depends on your logic I don't really know your project.

Comment: I do not quite understand what you're proposing. You're invited to answer [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44158384/how-to-provide-an-alternate-i18n-language-link-in-angular-with-aot-compiling).

Answer (score 0):

I use a Gulp 4 task to automate building of the app with Angular-cli. The gulp task will run the cli command to build the app and passes in the appropriate value to use for the base tag. I also use this task to deploy the files to the server (using gulp-rsync).

Here are some snippets from my gulpfile:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'staging';

if (environment === 'development') {
  console.log('No deploys performed for development environment.');
  process.exit(0);
}

gulp.task('build', gulp.series(build));

function build(done) {
  var cmd = spawn('ng', ['build', '--target=production', '--environment=' + environment, '--base-href=/app/'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
  cmd.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('Build task exited with code: ' + code);
    done(code);
  });
}
```