# How to configure the base href in angular with an environment variable of a tomcat or application servers?

Tags: angular, tomcat

I would like to know if you can configure the base href as an environment variable of a tomcat or application server.

for example:

index.html

```
<base href="/${environment.tomcat}/">
```

or an environment variable for the operating system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 base href from environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458650/angular-2-base-href-from-environment-variable)

Comment: I refer to environment variables of an application server, not of ng build --prod --base-href

Comment: @Dani check the solution

Comment: I answered a similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67091452/1843984

Answer (score 2):

> **`environment.ts`**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  tomcat: '/'
};
```

> **`environment.prod.ts`**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  tomcat: '/my-app/'
};
```

**And in your app module:~**

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: environment.tomcat}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

**OR**

**Using Angular CLI built-in feature:~**

```
# Sets base tag href to /myUrl/ in your index.html
ng build --base-href /myUrl/
ng build -bh /myUrl/
```

**you can update scripts in `package.json`:~**

```
"scripts": {
  //...
  "start": "ng serve -bh /anotherUrl/",
  "build": "ng build -bh /tomcatServerURL/",
  //..
},
```

**Hope this is helpful!**